# Printing hidden images, each to a different page of a PDF

Tags: javascript, css, image, printing, pdf-generation

I have a webpage that is 95% dynamically generated by user selections and content pulled from a DB.

As part of the website the user uses canvases (kind of like powerpoint) and save the completed canvases to images.  The images are then stored in the HTML in a div that has `display:none`.

What I want is the ability to click a button or just press print and have those images be the only things selected to print. Even better would be to print each individual image on a different page.

I have tried using @media print in various combinations with `display:none/block` and `visibility:hidden/visible`, but that does not seem to work, there is always residual content on the page.

In fact I cannot even see a print preview of the entire page without adding:

```
@media print{
 *{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Am I having CSS print problems b/c the contents of the page are created dynamically?  Or is there another question I should be asking?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-iterate my problem: I had images in html that were hidden in a div that was not displayed.  I wanted to print only those images to a PDF.

For those interested here is my solution. My HTML looks like this:

```
    <div id="head">
        <div id="img_group" style="display:none">
           <img href="img 1" />
           <img href="img 2" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents"></div>
```

I tried a CSS solution that did not exactly work: @Radoslaw M

```
    * {
    display: none;
    }
```

does not work because this overrides any `display: block;` that follows. So my solution was originally to combine `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` the following css worked to display only the `id="img_group` div:

```
    body{
      visibility:hidden;
    }
    #contents{
       display:none;
    }
    #img_group{
      visibility:visible;
    }
```

However the problem with this solution is that `visibility:hidden` leaves blank space where the div tags should have been.

Here was my round about solution.  I used some javascript, a print button, and jsPDF (http://jspdf.com/):

```
    <div id="head">
        <button id="print">Print</button>
        <div id="img_group" style="display:none">
           <img href="data:img 1" />
           <img href="data:img 2" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents"></div>

    <script>
       var doc = new jsPDF('landscape','pt', 'computer');
       var i = 0;
       $('#img_group').find('img').each(function(){
           if(i != 0){
              doc.addPage();
           }
           var imgData = $(this).attr('href');
           doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 1067, 600);
           i++;
       });
       doc.save('test.pdf');
    </script>
```

This solved my problem of printing these hidden images to a PDF and even allowed me to print each image to a different page in the PDF.  I hope this solution helps anyone else who has this problem in the future!